# Lodash & deepdash filter in tree with function

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering, lodash

I'm having trouble with lodash and deepdash, I need to filter a tree while keeping the parent / children architecture, sounds simple but I can't get it to work

Currently I'm filtering on the first level, it's working fine :

```
let search = 'lor',
    data = [{
      name: 'Lorem',
      id: 1,
      children: [{
        name: 'Ipsum',
        id: 3
      }, {
        name: 'Dolor',
        id: 5
      }]
    },{
      name: 'Sit',
      id: 2
    }, {
      name: 'Lorem ipsum',
      id: 4
    }];


let fileterdData = _.filter(data, function (o) {
     return o.name.toLowerCase().includes(search);
});
```

Filters works right when search = "lor";

I need to filter on the second level, so if I'm searching for "ipsum" I need as a result the filtered array with id=1 + its child id=3 (matching "ipsum") and id=4 (matching "ipsum").

Could someone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over children again to check if the search keyword exists as shown below:

```js
const search = 'ips';
const datas = [{
      name: 'Lorem',
      id: 1,
      children: [{
        name: 'Ipsum',
        id: 3
      }, {
        name: 'Dolor',
        id: 5
      }]
    },{
      name: 'Sit',
      id: 2
    }, {
      name: 'Lorem',
      id: 4
    }];

const includesName = (name = '') => name.toLowerCase().includes(search);

let fileterdData = _.filter(datas, data => {
    const { children, name } = data;

    return (
        !_.isEmpty(children)
            ? !!_.filter(children, child => includesName(child.name))
            : includesName(name)
    );
});

console.log(fileterdData);
```

Comment: Thanks! I managed to get it working with some modifications, I replied with the code.

Comment: @mgnrfk I have edited the code a bit, can you check now if this works. I guess it might not be working because of confusion with variable `name`. I know scope is different but still.

Answer (score 2):

if you are still interested in deepdash solution [here is an example](https://codepen.io/yurigor/pen/RwbEpGM?editors=0010) for your case:

```
let fileterdData = _.filterDeep(data,
  function (o) { return o.name.toLowerCase().includes('ipsum');},
  {childrenPath: 'children'});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do one more level filter. Here is simple plain js. change your code as per lodash  `_.filter`.

```js
let search = 'lor',
    data = [{
      name: 'Lorem',
      id: 1,
      children: [{
        name: 'Ipsum',
        id: 3
      }, {
        name: 'Dolor',
        id: 5
      }]
    },{
      name: 'Sit',
      id: 2
    }, {
      name: 'Lorem ipsum',
      id: 4
    }];
    
 //   let fileterdData = _.filter(data, function (o) {
 //   if(o.children){
  // o.children = _.filter(o.children, function (c) {
// return c.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1;
// });
//}
  //   return o.name.toLowerCase().includes(search);
//});


let fileterdData = data.filter(function (o) {
if(o.children){
o.children = o.children.filter((c)=>{
return c.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1;
});
}

return o.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1;
});

console.log(fileterdData);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actualy if you change the name at id=1 for something that doesn't pass the search match (like id:1, name: 'bar') I'd need to keep the parent + child, because the child matches the search.

I'll edit my first post accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Got it working (thanks Milind Agrawal) with some edits :

```
const includesName = (name = '') => name.toLowerCase().includes(search);

let filteredData = _.filter(data, data => {
    const { children, name } = data;
    return (
        !_.isEmpty(children)
            ? (
                !!_.filter(children, ({ name }) => includesName(name)).length ||
                includesName(name)
            )
            : includesName(name)
    );
});
```

In the ternary we'll check if the parent has the value too + checking for the children-filtered results length (doesn't work without it)

Comment: Sorry but it looks weird. `includesName` will return boolean value which with `.length` will return `undefined`. Am I missing anything?

Comment: The returned result is what _.filter() returns, which is the filtered array, see https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#filter